# NSAttributedString DocumentReadingOptionKey does not work in iOS 10

Tags: ios, encoding, nsattributedstring

I faced an issue that in iOS 8, `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding` caused run-time crash, so I had to get rid of it from options when I attempted to decode html data. But string didn't properly get encoded in iOS 10. So I tried to use `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey("CharacterEncoding")` which seems to be same as `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding` but it still didn't properly encode text in iOS 10. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try;

```
let string = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: messageData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey("CharacterEncoding"):String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
```